# How does x:Bind compare with the classical Binding, put as concisely as possible?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

How is the compiled binding, x:Bind, different from the *classical* Binding, put as concisely as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Compared with the *classical* binding you cannot use the following binding attributes with **x:Bind**: **ElementName**, **RelativeSource**, **Source** and **UpdateSourceTrigger**. Well, that almost sums up the limitations of **x:Bind** but **x:Bind** is powerful in its own right -- the notable one being *compiled binding* and hence the performance gain as a result. See last bullet point for another powerful thing in **x:Bind**'s armory.
- One important point to always remember: the data context of **x:Bind** is the code-behind class. To steer **x:Bind** to a ViewModel class, just prefix with the ViewModel object reference for page DataContext.
- Another point to remember is that the default binding Mode is **OneTime** while **OneWay** and **TwoWay** modes are also available. If a binding doesn't appear to be working, perhaps the binding is in default mode and past the **OneTime** trigger. To avoid such mishaps, define the binding Mode explicitly.
- My favorite -- binding for events using **x:Bind** -- now you can easily implement event-to-method pattern. In XAML, forget the `Tapped="MyTapHandlerInCodeBehind"` code and start using the **x:Bind** variant `Tapped="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyTapHandlerInViewModel}"`. One minor downside though is you cannot pass *Parameter* as with the *classical* event handler, but this is not common use case and an alternative exists.

Comment: That's cool, MSFT finally realized the value of default binding to the code behind.  This is a good thing for those that create user control almost exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The classic binding uses reflection to get the properties values to bind.  X:Bind creates a class at compile time for getting the values so the binding will be quicker