# Template10 PageHeader Text Binding Exception

Tags: win-universal-app, xamlparseexception, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm using Template10 for my UWP application and I want to update page header text dynamicly. Here is my XAML,

```
        <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Text="{Binding ViewModel.Title}">
            <!--place stretched, across top-->
            <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
        </controls:PageHeader>
```

Here is the exception message,

```
WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Template10.Controls.PageHeader.Text'. [Line: 57 Position: 73]

Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Failed to assign to property 'Template10.Controls.PageHeader.Text'. [Line: 57 Position: 73]
```

Without binding it works perfectly, but i need to dynamicly change it, any idea/workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Check *DataContext* and also remember that `x:Bind` is *OneTime* as default.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, instead of Binding I've used x:Bind, but there should not be difference except performance, still need to understand why..

Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}">

Comment: Because the default "Mode" of x:Bind is "OneTime", instead of "OneWay" like Binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this problem already (has been a while) here is what you should do.

First, make sure that the ViewModel is defined either in XAML page or code-behind page.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModelPage x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

*vm* is is the *namespace* for your ViewModel (e.g., MyAppProject.ViewModels) defined like below in the namespace declarations in the top:

```
xmlns:vm="using:MyAppProject.ViewModels"
```

while *ViewModelPage* is the the Type of ViewModel page that contains the *Title* property.

The same can be defined in view page code-behind as below (but prefer XAML as its is more readable in conjunction with you bindings in there)

```
public ViewModelPage ViewModel => this.DataContext as ViewModelPage ;
```

You need to put the **using** namespace declaration of the ViewModel at the top in the code-behind (in effect what you did for *vm* in XAML page).

With the **ViewModel** definition done right, you shouldn't get the *"...could not be found"* error.

Now for the binding: Use **x:Bind** because it's an improvement over the classical binding. See my answer [here explaining the advantages of x:Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848334/how-does-xbind-compare-with-the-classical-binding-put-as-concisely-as-possible). One important thing **to remember** is setting the binding **Mode** to "OneWay" (or "TwoWay" if this is applicable in some cases like updating a TextBox) rather than leave it to the default "OneTime" if **Mode** definition is missing.

Last but not least, ensure that the **Title** property raises the PropertyChanged event to update the binding (if you change the title dynamically). The ViewModel page should be well geared up to facilitate this: If you follow the **Template 10** pattern, the ViewModel page derives from **ViewModelBase** and properties have access to the **RaisePropertyChanged** method call, so your Title Property should look like:

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set { _title = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Title)); }
}
```

A different method name may be used for *RaisePropertyChanged*, such as *Set* or *SetProperty*. Sorry, if this comes a bit late but hope it helps.